# Different ways to implement two-way data binding for same component in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have an **Address** component that has basic address form with details like **name, street, city, state, country**.
I am using it for the **source** and **destination**.

Sample template

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id="src">
        <Address :address="src" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="dest">
        <Address :address="dest" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Address Component]
I am using **Vuex action (with module)** to get data from API (which may or may not return any address data ) and mutate in my store's state.

Sample state:

```
Address:{
    src:{
       name:'',
       street:'',
       city:'',
       state:'',
       country:'',   
    },
    dest:{
       name:'',
       street:'',
       city:'',
       state:'',
       country:'',   
    }
}
```

I want to achieve two-way data binding between my state and address components through mutation.

Address component for **src** should mutate **Address.src.(name, street, city, state, country)** in state and Address component for **dest** should mutate **Address.dest.(name, street, city, state, country)** in state

I tried using props and emit, [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields) by following this [post](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/form-fields-two-way-data-binding-and-vuex/), and it didn't work.

I don't know what is the proper way to implement it.

I am posting this question as a noob to get help in
what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, I follow the pattern below:

```sh
Make API Call --> data is updated in Vuex --> picked up by computed prop in component
```

Basically, in my component I can create a computed prop which fetches data from Vuex store, something like so:

```js
computed:{
  sourceAddress(){
    return this.$store.state.Address.src;
  },
  destinationAddress(){
    return this.$store.state.Address.dest;
  }
}
```

Then I can bind these computed props to my Address component like so:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" id="src">
        <Address :address="sourceAddress" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" id="dest">
        <Address :address="destinationAddress" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, whenever Address object will be updated in Vuex (via API call), these computed props will pick the change and update the Address component respectively.

```js
// sample pseudo code

mutations:{

  updateAddress(state, {type,payload}){
    if(type==="destination"){ 
       // update destination address
      }
    else { 
       //update source address
     }
    
  }

},

actions:{

  makeApiCall(context){
    // lets say call succeeds and you have some data to update for destination address
   context.commit('updateAddress',{type:"destination", payload:"data-you-want-to-update});
  }

}
```

Comment: This solves the data from vuex to Address component, How can I update the change in Address component in to vuex state ? I want to achieve two-way data binding @nishkaush

Comment: First define a `mutation` which when upon receiving data will update the state. Then call this mutation from within your `Vuex Action` (after API call is successful and actually contains some data to update).

Comment: @AkashPreet, if you are happy with the solution, could you mark it as the answer for future readers to follow. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vuex getters` to get your store data. Vue handles more elegant way of pulling the data(`two way binding`) into components using vuex helpers functions. You can read more about vuex helper functions [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper)

```
// store.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = {
   Address: {
    src: {
       name:'',
       street:'',
       city:'',
       state:'',
       country:'',   
    },
    dest: {
       name:'',
       street:'',
       city:'',
       state:'',
       country:'',   
    }
  }
}

const getters = {
   src: state => state.Address.src,
   desc: state => state.Address.desc
}

const mutations = {
  setSrc(state, srcObj) { // You can play around this to optimize if you can
    state.Address.src = srcObj
  },
  setDesc(state, descObj) {
    state.Address.desc = descObj
  }
}
const actions = {
   makeApiCall({ commit }, { type, params }) {
     yourApiCall(params).then((res) => {
       if (type === 'src') {  // You can play around this to optimize if you can
          commit('setSrc', res)
       } else {
          commit('setDesc', res)
       }
     })
   }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({ state, getters, mutations, actions})
```

```
//main.js
// all other imports

import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

```
In your component

<Address :address="src"/>
<Address :address="desc"/>

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['src', 'desc']) // these are updated automatically when store changes and available on this.src/this.desc 
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['makeApiCall']) // you can directly call using this // this.makeApiCall({ type: 'src', params: {} }) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Naren, But it still wont solve the issue. I want to mutate the state if we change the value in Address component's input fields. Eg: If API returns Address.src.name as Naren (which will be stored in state) then page will load with Naren in Address's name input field. If I change Naren to Akash then it should mutate in state (Address.src.name should be Akash now).

Comment: you should not change the state directly, you should be doing with only with mutations. As per Vuex Docs: `The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation`, read [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations) for more information

Comment: If you want to change the state from input field, add mutation in the store and update the state with that mutation. `const mutations = { changeName(state, name) { state.Address.name = name }}`